# PHP: Environment variable not readable by getenv()

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, debian-based

I am using .htaccess file for setting an environment variable

```
SetEnv ENV "development"
```

It can be read by $_SERVER['ENV'] but not by getenv('ENV');
For getenv() I have to use

```
putenv('ENV=development');
```

Don't know why variable which is set in .htaccess is not readable by getenv().

Edit:
Because I am using a foreign script where "ENV" is asked I did not realise that just the name "ENV" is causing trouble (reserved?).
A test with just another environment variable name works as expected

```
SetEnv REDIRECT_ENV "development"
```

Edit 2:
Environment is Apache 2.2, fastcgi, debian wheezy, php5.4.4
I noticed this behaviour on VirtualBox VM and on rooted server online with same components

Comment: @WereWolf: that's great to know ;) Did you test it with "ENV"?

Comment: Yes, I tested it first and then commented.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with mod_rewrite to detect env:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:stage]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]
```

and

```
SetEnvIf Host ^stage\.example\.com$ PYRO_ENV=stage
SetEnvIf Host ^(www\.)?example\.com$ PYRO_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks for your variations, but all of them don't work if the name is "ENV". Just another variable name does it.

Comment: So maybe "ENV" is a reserved word in this situation. Could you perhaps use another term? Afterall, its just another variable name, right?

Comment: Yes I ENV is reserved. Cehck here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php